# How to let a user enter a list of items in a JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

How do you specify a structure to validate a list of items, say strings, by a user in a JSON Schema?

This is what I have so far:

```
"list_of_str": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
         "type": "string"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> res = {
...     "type": "array",
...     "items": {
...          "type": "string"
...     }
... }
>>> 
>>> one = ["one", "two"]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> validictory.validate(one, res)
>>> # No error
```

"validictory is a general purpose Python data validator that allows validation of arbitrary Python data structures." (see this -> [Validictory docs](https://readthedocs.org/projects/validictory/))

Comment: Thanks Alberto! Very helpful. Will look into this easy validator.

Comment: Here you have a very nice tutorial http://www.alexconrad.org/2011/10/json-validation.html

Comment: Have been using 'validate' so far from jsonschema https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema

Comment: Yes, validictory uses code derived from jsonschema :) I think it is very easy and powerful!